# How to use const InputIterators to write a function for generic containers?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, iterator, constants

I'm trying to understand how to write a (stand-alone)function that takes const InputIterators and does something simple while iterating over every element in the container. For simplicity, I'm considering a simple print function, that would print all elements in the range between `[first..last)`, but the function is not allowed to modify the elements in the container. Here's what I've got so far:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

template<class InputIterator>
void print(const InputIterator& first, const InputIterator& last)
{
  while (first != last) {
    cout << *first << " ";
    ++first;
  }
  cout << endl;
}


int main()
{
  vector<int> v;
  v.push_back(1);
  v.push_back(3);
  v.push_back(5);
  v.push_back(7);

  list<float> l;
  l.push_back(11.1);
  l.push_back(33.3);
  l.push_back(55.7);
  l.push_back(77.7);

  print(v.cbegin(), v.cend());
  print(l.cbegin(), l.cend());    
}
```

When I try to compile the code (using gcc4.7 with c++11 flag), I get the following errors:

```
iterator.cpp: In instantiation of 'void print(const InputIterator&, const InputIterator&) [with InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >]':
iterator.cpp:32:29:   required from here
iterator.cpp:12:5: error: passing 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >' as 'this' argument of '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>& __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator++() [with _Iterator = const int*; _Container = std::vector<int>; __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container> = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const int*, std::vector<int> >]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
iterator.cpp: In instantiation of 'void print(const InputIterator&, const InputIterator&) [with InputIterator = std::_List_const_iterator<float>]':
iterator.cpp:33:29:   required from here
iterator.cpp:12:5: error: passing 'const std::_List_const_iterator<float>' as 'this' argument of 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Tp>::_Self& std::_List_const_iterator<_Tp>::operator++() [with _Tp = float; std::_List_const_iterator<_Tp>::_Self = std::_List_const_iterator<float>]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

I've noticed that the code works fine if I removed the `const` requirement, replacing the `cbegin` and `cend` with `begin` and `end` respectively. Can someone please point out what I'm missing here?

Comment: first is declared const, yet you try to modify it: `++first;`

Comment: what you want is a `const_iterator` not a `const iterator`

Comment: Pass the iterators by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass your iterators *by value*:

```
template <class InputIterator>
void print(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
{
    // as before
}
```

The contract that `print` will not modify any of the contents is implicit by you never assigning to `*first`.

You *do* need to modify the iterators themselves (to actually do any iteration), which is you can't take them by `const&` (otherwise, first thing you'd have to copy them again) - but modifying the iterator isn't the same as modifying the underlying contents.

Comment: I think the contract is by the name `InputIterator`, which is *an iterator to read from*, as opposed to, *an iterator to write to*, for which there exists `OutputIterator`.

Comment: @Nawaz That's not a real contract - it's just a naming convention. If we had concepts and you could do `template <InputIterator It>`, then yes.

Comment: @Nawaz The name does not matter at all - it is just the placeholder for the template type. You can replace it by T and the answer would still work. I didn't know that before as well :P

Comment: @Barry: I *know* it is just a name. But it tells the *external* world that it will not modify the content, though currently there is no way the compiler can enforce this at compile time, to see any violation. It is named `InputIterator` for a reason, not just `Iterator`.

Comment: @Barry It's something that's written down, something that the author (A) intended to have a specific meaning about requirements placed on another party (B), and something that A intended to be a promise to B that should B meet those requirements, A will provide a function that's actually useful to B. That is just as much a contract as most other things called contracts.

Comment: ... also, the users are not expected to look at the implementation to be sure that you're making an implicit contract that you're not assigning to `*first`, as your answer currently says. Such contract should be announced (and facilitated) by the language (that is ideal), but if that is not possible, then it should at least announced by naming convention and proper documentation, which is what I meant.

Comment: @TCSGrad: Please, read my above comments which clarify what I meant in my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion seems to stem from mixing Iterators and the data pointed to by iterators.

- Iterator can be mutated, while keeping the pointed-to read-only.

Let's map these concepts to raw pointers:

```
int buffer[ARRAY_SIZE];

const int *ptr2c = &(buffer[0]);
```

Vs.

```
int * const cptr = &(buffer[0]);
```

Consider looping over the elements of 'buffer', using either of these pointers. With 'ptr2c', one should be able to loop over the array; no modifications to the array elements possible via this variable.

On the other hand, 'cptr', a const-pointer-to-int, lets you modify the pointed-to element in the array. But, cptr itself can't be modified to point to any other location.

Mapping back to your example, 'const InputIterator' makes the iterator itself unmodifiable, which is not what you want. This is crude, but, you could visualize Iterators in terms of pointers. Of course, the concepts quickly diverge afterwards.